# how do you add img tags in an unordered list in css right?

Tags: html, css, joomla

I'm trying to create a bulleted list in joomla. temple css

I added the code to the template css file, but the image never appears. What could be the cause of the bug?

```css
ul li.Selfclean {list-style:url("./images/com_droppics/17/cleanIcon50.png")left top no-repeat;}
```

```html
<li class="Selfclean">
<h3>Title</h3>
</li>
```

this code I added to the template.

```
ul li.Selfclean {list-style:url("./images/com_droppics/17/cleanIcon50.png")left top no-repeat;}
```

thank your for you help )

Comment: read the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/list-style .. there no left/top/no-repeat in list-style, it's not a background

Answer (score 0):

You used illegal attributes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style for available options.

The following example works, except the used logo is too big ;).
Also, using `h3` inside `li` makes it move the header to a new line, I'm not sure if that's the effect you wanted to achieve.

```css
li.Selfclean {
  list-style: url("https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/icons/cc.png");
}
```

```html
<li class="Selfclean">Title</li>
```